# user: Lookup requires cgo

Tags: go, cgo

After cross compiling and [testing an app](https://github.com/immortal/immortal/issues/10), I got this error:

```
user: Lookup requires cgo
```

If I am right currently there is no way to fix this rather than compiling directly on the target architecture.

Setting up multiple architectures is not a simple task, therefore wondering what could it be done as workaround to this.

For my use case, I need to verify if a user exists on the system in order to run a command on behalf that user, before calling commands like `who`, `id` are there any `syscalls` or go native methods that could allow me to get this information not depending on `cgo`?

Comment: Do you need to verify a user exists at all, or that the current process is run by a specific user?

Comment: @JimB good point, I need only to run the process on behalf a specific user, currently using `&syscall.Credential{Uid: uint32(uid), Gid: uint32(gid)}`

Comment: Then no. Looking up uid/gid requires system specific calls, and libc calls on unix.